# Check if MySQL Replication is in sync

Tags: mysql, replication, checksum

The MySQL documentation about CHECKSUM TABLE is very minimalistic.

My question: Is CHECKSUM TABLE a good way of checking if a MySQL Slave Table is in sync with the master? In other words: Can i use the checksums to verify that the slave table is equal to the master table?

I can't use Seconds_Behind_Master indicator because of changes only made in the slave table.

Comment: Why not use the documented [SHOW SLAVE STATUS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-administration-status.html) SQL statement?

Comment: for example i change the slave table - the table differs from the master table. i can't track this using show slave status

Comment: You can take specific tables out of replication if they change in the slave server, then you can use "show slave status"

Comment: http://pastebin.com/PENkCyRR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CHECKSUM TABLE is a good way. Instead of running it directly, take a look at [pt-table-checksum](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-table-checksum.html).

Once you ensure it's in sync, You should make the slave [read-only](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_read_only) so you *can't* change its tables.

Comment: pt-table-checksum is the right way to check data consistency between master and slave: 1) you don't need to stop replication 2) it's not affecting MySQL performance. just one note - revoke SUPER from everybody, but root account, set slave read-only and only then run pt-table-checksum

Comment: thx, here's my first python script that runs through some mysql servers (username, password, database name must be the same) and prints checksums and line count of the tables

Comment: http://pastebin.com/PENkCyRR

Answer (score 1):

It's generally considered good (best?) practice to make secondary servers read only to help prevet just what you're trying to detect.

```
set global read_only =1;
```

or

```
read_only=1
```

in the my.cnf file. This doesn't stop users with SUPER privilege from making changes though so you should also remove that from accounts that don't need it

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET super_priv='N' WHERE user<>'root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then only use unprivileged accounts to work with the databases and the root account for when you need [SUPER Privilege](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super).